# Google Places not installing as a pod

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have 3 pods already installed in my project including Google Maps. However I'm having problems installing Google Places and Google Place Picker. Nothing happens when I use pod install. Hmmm!

Comment: What error you are getting.?

Comment: What does your Podfile look like?

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!


target 'BluuPin' do
 pod 'GoogleMaps'
 pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
 pod 'GooglePlaces'
 pod 'Alamofire'
 pod 'SwiftyJSON'

end

No errors, nothing happens outside Google Maps, Alamofire and SwiftyJson populate while the other 2 don't.

Comment: https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipMVcFDVlpOgYmZikhD6RHEm9g84ODX2yKblhul8

Comment: Turns out I had 2 podfiles. I was editing nano pod when nano podfile was in fact the original. Everything works now,thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

**It may be due to Static Library-**

Until GoogleMaps is released as a dynamic framework, you can only support it as a transitive dependency as a library. However, as you are using a swift framework - you can't support that either. Your best option is to request Google release their libraries as a dynamic framework.

You can try to download them manually and insert them but I think it will not work neither.

**I suggest you to read** [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2926) **discussion**.

Comment: Google Maps works! Google Places and Place Picker don't.